# VBA function to add a value to cells in range and get product

Tags: excel, function, vba

I've been tearing my hair out over this and after endless searching online still can't find the answer.

Here's a quick summary of what I'm looking for an a longer explanation below!

I need a VBA function to replicate a formula similar to this: {=product(A:A+1)}. This goes through every cell in column A where there is a number and adds 1, then multiplies. This can be done using either (1) Evaluate unless there are blanks or text in the range, which gives an error or (2) worksheetfunction.product, but it doesn't like it when I look through the range and add 1.

If anyone can figure out a solution for using either of these options I would be over the moon. I may also be missing something very basic!

Longer version...

What I'm trying to do:
Create three VBA functions that calculate 1) compound return 2) annualised compound return and 3) annualised volatility. These would be for variable ranges and for the annualised functions you can also specify whether it is days, months or years. For example, the compound return function when used would look something "=compoundreturn(range,number of periods)"

The calculations are easy using formula but I want to create functions to make it a quick process.

I can get all three to work through VBA using EVALUATE.

They look like this,

```
Function PerRet(rng As range)
    PerRet = Worksheet.Evaluate("=exp(sumproduct(ln(" & rng.Address & "+1)))-1")
End Function

Function AnnRet(rng As range, np As Double)
    AnnRet = Evaluate("=exp((Average(ln(" & rng.Address & "+1)))*" & np & ")-1")
End Function

Function AnnVol(rng As range, np As Double)
    AnnVol = Worksheet.Evaluate("=stdev.s(ln(" & rng.Address & "+1))*sqrt(" & np & ")")
End Function
```

The problem is that the range selected may sometimes by the entire column, which contains blanks and potentially text. Functions like AVERAGE or STDEV.S will ignore these when you are just using them in formulas. Unfortunately, they don't do this when using Evaluate.

I know that instead of using Evaluate for AVERAGE, I could use `worksheetfunction.average`, which would then ignore the blanks and text. But here I come across another problem in that part of the function has to look through a range of returns (postiive and negative) and add 1 to each before averaging. This doesn't seem to work for a range unless that range is simply one cell.

An example of what I have so far for this is

```
Function AnnRet(rng As range, np As Double)  
    AnnRet = exp(WorksheetFunction.Average(WorksheetFunction.Ln(rng + 1)) * np) - 1      
End Function
```

Any ideas how I can make it add 1 to each of the cells in the range before getting the Ln and then averaging?

Many thanks for looking
Duncan

Answer (score 0):

A little *light* testing suggests something along these lines might work:

```
Sub Tester()
Dim v

    v = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("=SUM(IF(ISBLANK(A:A),false,A:A+1))")

    Debug.Print v

End Sub
```

I just had a few numbers in ColA and it only added (number+1) where the cell was populated - ie. it did not also sum up a bunch of 1's where cells were empty.

**EDIT:**

After your comments about problem with non-numeric cells, a little more testing comes up with something like:

```
Function Tester(rng As Range)
Dim v, f

    f = "=AVERAGE(IF(ISBLANK({a}),FALSE,IF(ISNUMBER({a}),LN({a}+1),FALSE)))"

    'remove any unsed part of the input range (for performance)
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(rng, rng.Parent.UsedRange)

    v = rng.Parent.Evaluate(Replace(f, "{a}", rng.Address(False, False)))


    Tester = v

End Function
```

This first filters out blanks  - non-blanks can then safely be passed to ISNUMBER() to filter out non-numeric cells. This is not quite at your final formula but not far off.  Do you have some inputs and expected output for testing?

**EDIT 2:**

Using `Intersect()` to restrict a full-column input range to only the "used" part of the sheet seems to improve performace significantly (by ~100x when I only had a thousand values in the range).

Comment: thanks Tim. That works well for ignoring blank cells but not where there is text in cells. I tried the same formula with 'isnumber', which works when used as a formula in excel but bizarrely doesn't work using Evaluate in VBA. Any ideas why? This is the formula I tried to replicate '=EXP(AVERAGE(IF(ISNUMBER(S:S),LN(S:S+1),FALSE))*12)-1' and this is what I came up with 'Evaluate("=exp(Average(if(isnumber(" & rng.Address & "),ln(" & rng.Address & "+1),false))*" & np & ")-1")', where 'rng' is my range and 'np' would be 12. Ideally I'd like to do this all without Evaluate for speed.

Comment: Fantastic, this works well for me Tim, thanks very much!

Comment: Sorry, one last, somewhat related question if you don't mind. Say I want to run my function on multiple sheets in a workbook, replacing a function that is currently used. To quickly replace all the cells in the workbook using this function, I can do "replace all". However, when I do this, all the cells in the workbook that use this function return the value for the cell in the current sheet I have open. Is there a way to make the function work independently for each of the cells in which it is used?

Comment: I don't see that behavior (but I don't have your exact formula).  Assuming the input range is on the same sheet as the formula cell, it should return a the appropriate value, since we're always evaluating in the context of `rng.Parent`.  Can you share your workbook (or at least something which shows the problem you're having)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to share my workbook but here's a basic example: In Sheet 1 I have numbers in column A, and in cell B1 I have the function referencing column A. In Sheet 2 I have exactly the same setup. While in Sheet 2 I go to Find>Replace, and replace all in within workbook. I replace the old function with the new function. So in Sheet 2, cell B1 I have the correct value calculated but when I go into Sheet 1, cell B1 has the same value as in Sheet 2, rather than calculating it's own value. Does this make sense?!

Comment: Tim, I was making an horrific mistake of leaving "Evaluate" in. Took that out and works a charm. Thanks very much for all your help.